# How to use gpg on a phone with --batch --gen-key?

Tags: android, c++, encryption, adb, gnupg

I have been working on this problem for a while now and seem to have found no answer with all the pieces I am looking for. I have a c++ program and I am trying to use a system call that looks like

```
system("/data/data/info.guardianproject.gpg/app_opt/aliases/gpg --batch --gen-key /footoo");
```

This has not worked for me yet though.

When I use adb shell to call this from the phones shell terminal it works and then asks me for the passphrase. When I run the program it does not do anything.

The footoo is just a file that is on the phone that contains the correct information to work with the --batch command. Like I said earlier it did work when I just called it from the adb shell. I have the GnuPG app installed on the phone.

Also I was wondering if this was even possible to do if the phone was unrooted? If somebody could offer some advice I would appreciate that very much.
Also here is the footoo file

```
%echo Its starting lets hope it works
Key-Type: RSA   
Key-Length: 2048
Expire-Date: 0
Passphrase: testing123
Name-Real: Tester
Name-Email: tester@tester.com
#now do a commit so we can echo when we are done
%commit
%echo done
```

Thanks.

Comment: There are libraries from Bouncy Castle available to perform PGP operations. Have you tried using those instead of going into the shell? That seems a whole lot easier to me.

Comment: I have not I might look into that but I have a bunch of existing code that  runs on blackfin and windows that I want to run on android so I am trying to change this code as little as possible.